# Does Box-Cox parameter estimation ever arrive at lambda=0?

Tags: r, statistics

Does Box-Cox parameter estimation ever arrive at lambda=0?  Such that the recommended transform is a log function?  Or is that possibility just a mathematical nicety to make the function continuous, but one that rarely gets used in practice?

I ask because I have been trying to test a Box Cox transform in R to see if it estimates `lambda==0` when appropriate:

```
> require(car)
> x <- exp(qnorm(runif(1000))) # 1000 numbers from a normal distribution then exp()
> p = powerTransform(x)
> p
Estimated transformation parameters
     x
-0.1098415
# clearly this does not equal zero
```

Comment: You might also find some use for `boxcox()` in the `MASS` package.

Comment: Is one better than the other?  I keep getting errors in `powerTransform` - NaNs, nonconvergence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your standards to "close enough". When I do that same procedure with whatever my random.seed is at the moment I get

```
>  p
Estimated transformation parameters 
         x 
0.01389905
```

And my further experiments suggest your value is on the "outlier" region of the distribution. When I do that 1000 times I don't even get a value as extreme as yours:

```
v <- vector("numeric", 1000)
for (i in 1:1000) {x <- exp(qnorm(runif(1000)))
                   v[i] = powerTransform(x)$lambda}
Hmisc::describe(v)
v 
        n   missing    unique      Mean       .05       .10 
     1000         0      1000 -0.000212 -0.039335 -0.033698 
      .25       .50       .75       .90       .95 
-0.017978 -0.001259  0.017593  0.033499  0.044303 

lowest : -0.09670 -0.09472 -0.08878 -0.08456 -0.07255
highest:  0.06730  0.06830  0.06932  0.06955  0.07142
```

In addition to Venables & Ripley's MASS::boxcox mentioned by @Josh O'Brien,  there is also a car::boxCox function in John Fox's package's extensive suite of regression diagnostic functions (which you already have loaded).

Comment: Ok.  I guess what bothers me is is there such a thing as 'close enough'?  Seeing as `log x` is fundamentally different to `x^(very small number)`... if I think my data might deserve a log transform should I be contented with `x^(very small number)` instead?

Comment: In many ways a log transform does do much the same as a fractional power transform. They both limit the variance explosion that occurs at upper ranges. I think you have wandered out of "R how" territory into either philosophy or abstract probability. This line of question might better be re-addressed on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The fact you think that kind of answers the question :)

Comment: I agree that this could go to stats.stackexchange.com: I think you could choose between "use a sensible round number within the confidence intervals of lambda-hat" or "use lambda-hat" depending on your goals and philosophy ...

Comment: To bring this back to reality - I'm doing automated transforms on a large number of variables.  Just curious to see what happens to exponentially distributed ones.  Thanks for your comments.  Btw does anyone know if there's anything to choose between `powerTransform()` vs `boxcox()` in the `MASS` package?

Answer (score 5):

Since the data is random, you do not get exactly zero.

```
> p <- powerTransform(rlnorm(100))
> coef(p)
rlnorm(100) 
-0.05007203 
> coef(p, round=TRUE) # Recommended transform
rlnorm(100) 
          0
```

If you remove the randomness, the value is much closer to zero.

```
> p <- powerTransform(qlnorm(ppoints(100)))
> p
Estimated transformation parameters 
qlnorm(ppoints(100)) 
       -2.635191e-12
```